# Getting values of GeoJSON after is loaded in OpenLayers6 with DragAndDrop

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I am using the DragAndDrop functionality of OpenLayers6 in order to load GeoJSON  data in the browser. Once I load the data, I get the map.

Now I am interested in using the same functionality for filling up also other elements in the page (e.g. charts).

Below part of the code:

```
var my_DragAndDrop = map.addInteraction(new DragAndDrop({
  source: source,
  formatConstructors: [GeoJSON]
}));

//! [json data outside the map]
source.on('addfeature', function(evt) {
    console.log(source)
});
```

I am trying to acquire the JSON values after the map is loaded. I am not sure, which event listener to use but it seems like that `addfeature` does the trick. Do you know what would be the proper way to retrieve the JSON values inside this event listener?

**UPDATE**

Based on Mike's comments I have managed to retrieve the geoJSON for the layer as below

```
var listenerKey = source.on('change', function(e) {
  values = new GeoJSON().writeFeatures(source.getFeatures());
  console.log(JSON.parse(values));
});
```

However this code returns all the geojson along with the coordinates etc. How can I retrieve only the properties of the geojson? For example something like:

```
var id = source.getFeatures('id');
```

Comment: You could use `new GeoJSON.writeFeatures(source.getFeatures())` for the whole collection or `new GeoJSON.writeFeature(evt.feature)` for individual feature

Comment: Thanks. When I try this I get: ol_format_GeoJSON__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.writeFeatures is not a constructor

Comment: It should have been `new GeoJSON().writeFeatures(....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a javascript array map to extract the id and properties collection from the features in a json

```
console.log(JSON.parse(values).features.map(function(value){ return { id: value.id, properties: value.properties }; }));
```